# Find $\int_0^{y^2}e^{-xy}dx$ using the Leibnitz integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^{y^2}e^{-xy}dx$$

The Leibnitz integral rule states that:
$$\frac{d}{dy}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x,y)dx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})dx$$

However I can't seem to get this to help me. I find that I have to integrate by parts which gives me the original problem back.

Comment: why you have to use this rule? you can simply integrate it

Comment: I was asked to in my problem sheet

Comment: the result is $\frac{e^{y^3}-1}{y}$

Comment: It is not clear to me how the Leibnitz rule helps here. Sometimes it results in a simple ODE. Incidentally. you need a slightly different rule here since the bounds are functions of $y$.

Comment: The [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement) is for differentiating an integral with respect to a variable that appears both in the limits of integration and the integrand. This is not the situation you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the Leibniz integral rule is not for this situation. Instead, just integrate it outright:

$$
\int_0^{y^2} e^{-xy}\,dx={e^{-xy}\over -y}\Bigg|_{x=0}^{x=y^2}={e^{-y^3}\over -y}-{1\over -y}={1-e^{-y^3}\over y}.$$

---

Perhaps you were asked to find ${d\over dy}\int_0^{y^2} e^{-xy}\,dx$? Now *that* would summon the Leibniz rule...